# Compare dates by month and day only

Tags: mysql, date

I have got `date` field in my `foos` table. So now I need to select all foos from date interval but comparing only month and day.

For example, I need to select all foos 10 days before and after `7 Jan 2012` -> `28 Dec - 17 Jan`. Or week around `10 Jul 2009` -> `3 Jul - 17 Jul`. It should select depending only on month and day through all years.

My raw and naive solution

```
SELECT b_date FROM foos 
  WHERE DAYOFYEAR(b_date) BETWEEN 
    DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND (DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) + 20)
  OR DAYOFYEAR(b_date) BETWEEN 
    (DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY) - 20) AND DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
  GROUP BY foos.id;
```

Comment: Do you want dates between `28 Dec 2011` and `17 Jan 2012` in the first example? Or dates in **any year**, between  `28 Dec` and `17 Jan`?

Comment: It should be independent from year. SO it should be more or equal then `28 Dec` in any year and less or equal then `17 Jan` in any year. So `31 Dec 1995` and `10 Jan 1940` will fit my needs

Comment: I think your answer is fine and you can post it as an answer. (It won't be very fast with a big table, but I guess that's not an issue, here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b_date FROM foos 
  WHERE DAYOFYEAR(b_date) BETWEEN 
    DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND (DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) + 21)
  OR DAYOFYEAR(b_date) BETWEEN 
    (DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY) - 21) AND DAYOFYEAR('2011-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY)
  GROUP BY foos.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find all dates dates `28 Dec 2011` and `17 Jan 2012`, you can use this:

```
WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN '2012-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY
                     AND '2012-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

---

For the more general problem, I see 2 approaches. An easy to write, but probably slow with a  big `foos` table:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM 
      foos AS f
  CROSS JOIN
      ( SELECT 32 * MONTH(StartDate) + DAY(StartDate)
                 AS StartCheck
             , 32 * MONTH(EndDate) + DAY(EndDate)
                 AS EndCheck 
        FROM
            ( SELECT ('2012-01-07' - INTERVAL 10 DAY) AS StartDate 
                   , ('2012-01-07' + INTERVAL 10 DAY) AS EndDate 
            ) AS c
      ) AS cc
WHERE 32*MONTH(f.DateColumn)+DAY(f.DateColumn) BETWEEN StartCheck 
                                                   AND EndCheck 
   OR  StartCheck > EndCheck 
   AND 32*MONTH(f.DateColumn)+DAY(f.DateColumn) NOT BETWEEN EndCheck + 1
                                                        AND StartCheck - 1
```

Comment: what do you think about my solution? it looks shorter

Comment: Yes, much shorter. And probably much easier to understand what it does :)

Comment: But the `-20` and `+20` should have `21`.